# Tengo problemas con las librerias de JS para creacion documentos .docx y descargarlos

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, visual-studio

Intento conectar un formulario con datos básicos de html con un botón, que al darle clic me capture y envíe los datos ingresados en el formulario(nombre, apellido, dirección y correo) a un documento nuevo de word y paso seguido lo descargue.

Mi IDE es Visual Studio Code al cual ya le instale todas las dependencia necesarias del Node.js, pero con solo abrir el formulario en el navegador con el Live Server de Visual me sale este error:
Imagen #1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he podido solucionarla, mis conocimientos son muy básicos y la idea de todo es aprendiendo haciendo pequeños proyectos en este caso un "Generador de Documentos" pero no soy muy bueno al parecer.

Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo, cuales son las librerias que me hacen falta? o por que el servidor de Visual no se conecta o por que me sale ese error? o alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacer lo mismo con otro lenguaje o que se yo, tengo un poco mas de experiencia 4/10 en java.

Comment: 1. VS Code es un editor de código, no un IDE.
2. ¿Dónde esta el código? No sabemos que estas haciendo.